# Clustering by number of spacial nodes in an area

Tags: clustering

I have a huge a amount of coordinates (hundred of millions) and I want to group them in areas, where every area should have approximately the same number of nodes and no more than a limit.

I was thinking about implementing a RTree so every Leaf will be an area, but because the amount of data, maybe there is a better way using some clustering algorithm.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.